# Entity Framework 5 code first - Documentation in database

Tags: .net, frameworks, entity

My question is simple but I don´t find the answer anywhere.
Is there some annotation (attribute) or way to write some documentation at field level that will be reflected in the description (in sql server, but there's equivalents in other dbs) property of the column in the database?

My concern is for example in enum fields, write in the description of the column in the database to what "string" maps the integer value stored in that field.

Thank you in advance, 
                      Gustavo

Comment: As for migrations, you can't : http://bit.ly/QiL6y1 (look for "AddColumnOperation"). 

But you can probably do it manually : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1985254/sql-server-can-you-add-field-descriptions-in-create-table